# Компонент Symfony Messenger теряет соединение и дублирует сохранение записей

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Настраиваю компонент Messenger в Symfony 4.4.

Схема работы такая: отправляю в контролер json (далее преобразую json в объект) -> затем отправляю объект в очередь(в качестве транспорта использую доктрин) -> далее хендлер вычитывает сообщение и сохраняет объект в БД. Проблема: при асинхронной обработки сообщений, сохраняется несколько дублей объекта в БД + хенделер пишет об ошибках в соединении (см скрин).

Нашел описание этой проблемы на symfony casts, там предлагают при сохранении объекта в БД использовать функцию flush, без предварительного использовании функции persist. При таком подходе сохранение в БД не происходит.

При синхронном сохранении, такой ошибки не происходит.

Кто-н знает решение этой проблемы?

ApiController:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/api/task")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param MessageBusInterface $messageBus
 * @return Response
 */
public function createTask(Request $request, MessageBusInterface $messageBus): Response
{
    try {
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();

        $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(),
            InputCalculatorTaskDto::class,
            'json');

        $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto
            ->setTaskGuid(Uuid::uuid4())
            ->setServiceName(ServicesListEnum::SERVICE_CALULATOR)
            ->setTaskName(TaskListEnum::CALCULATE_ORDER_PRICE)
            ->setCreatedAt(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE)));

        $calculatorTaskMessage = new CalculatorTaskMessage($this->inputCalculatorTaskDto);
        $messageBus->dispatch($calculatorTaskMessage);

        $this->logger->info('done ' . $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto->getTaskGuid());

        return new Response('done');

    } catch (\Throwable $t) {
        $this->logger->error($t->getMessage());

        return new Response('error ' . $t->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Messanger:

```
class CalculatorTaskMessage
{
    /**
     * @var InputCalculatorTaskDto
     */
    private InputCalculatorTaskDto $inputCalculatorTaskDto;

    public function __construct(InputCalculatorTaskDto $inputCalculatorTaskDto)
    {
        $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto = $inputCalculatorTaskDto;
    }

    /**
     * @return InputCalculatorTaskDto
     */
    public function getInputCalculatorTaskDto(): InputCalculatorTaskDto
    {
        return $this->inputCalculatorTaskDto;
    }
}
```

MessageHandler

class CalculatorNewTaskCreatorHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
public InputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntityImpl $inputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntity;
public EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
public TasksRepository $tasksRepository;
private CalculatorTaskProducer $calculatorTaskProducer;

```
    /**
     * CalculatorTaskCreatorHandler constructor.
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param TasksRepository $tasksRepository
     * @param CalculatorTaskProducer $calculatorTaskProducer
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
                                TasksRepository $tasksRepository,
                                CalculatorTaskProducer $calculatorTaskProducer)
    {
        $this->inputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntity = new InputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntityImpl();
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->tasksRepository = $tasksRepository;
        $this->calculatorTaskProducer = $calculatorTaskProducer;
    }

    public function __invoke(CalculatorTaskMessage $calculatorTaskMessage)
    {
        $inputCalculatorTaskDto = $calculatorTaskMessage->getInputCalculatorTaskDto();
        $tasks = $this->inputCalculatorTaskDtoToTaskEntity->map($inputCalculatorTaskDto);

        $this->entityManager->persist($tasks);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        $this->calculatorTaskProducer->sendMessage($inputCalculatorTaskDto);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну ваш консьюмер очевидно заканчивает работу с ошибкой и заново обрабатывает сообщение. Ищите почему ошибка.

Comment: Да, это действительно так. Как только поставил обработку ошибок консьюмера, дублирование объектов прекратилось

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в консьюмере rabbit. Как только была добавлена обработка ошибок для консьюмера, дублирование объектов прекратилось